# Fusing IMU sensor with odometry

Tags: odometry, sensor-fusion, estimation

Would fusing Odometry estimation with IMU sensor increase the accuracy of estimation for planar differential drive robots?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

Example of this can be found [here](https://hackernoon.com/ghost-iv-sensor-fusion-encoders-imu-c099dd40a7b).

Depending on how good your modeling is you could also use the IMU to help detect wheel slippage.

Comment: Thank you. The link is quite helpful.